# How to get BucketSort algorithm working?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, bucket-sort

I am trying to create a bucketsort algorithm in C++, but it is not working at all. Every run, it adds many new numbers, often very large, such as in the billions, into the array. Does anyone know why this is? Here is the code - (Note that I am passing in an array of size 100, with random numbers from 0 to ~37000, and that the insertion sort function is fully functional and tested multiple times)

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could point out what's wrong.

```
void bucketSort(int* n, int k) 
{
    int c = int(floor(k/10)), s = *n, l = *n;
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        if(s > *(n + i)) s = *(n + i);
        else if(l < *(n + i)) l = *(n + i);
    }
    int bucket[c][k + 1];
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        bucket[i][k] = 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
            if(*(n + i) >= (l - s)*j/c) {
                continue;
            } else {
                bucket[j][bucket[j][k]++] = *(n + i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++) {
        insertionSort(&bucket[i][0], k);
    }
}
```

Comment: `bucket[j][bucket[j][k]++] = *(n + i);` Is that really what you mean? It looks wrong.

Comment: The last index I used as a counter for which index to use; I don't see what's wrong with that line

Comment: Why do you use `*(n + i)` instead of `n[i]`? Did you get that from some awful book or tutorial?

Comment: I'm self-taught; can you call a pointer's value like that?

Comment: Although the expressions `n[i]`, `i[n]`, `*(n+i)`, `*(i+n)` all produce the same result it's most common to use the traditional `n[i]` array notation. Using `*(n+i)` has no performance advantage and I think it makes the code harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line does not compile. `int bucket[c][k + 1];`

I think the problem is with you bucket indices. This part here

```
for(int j = 0; j < c; j++) {
   if(*(n + i) >= (l - s)*j/c) {
        continue;
   } else {
        bucket[j][bucket[j][k]++] = *(n + i);
        break;
   }
}
```

does not do the equivalent of:

```
  insert n[i] into bucket[ bucketIndexFor( n[i]) ]
```

First it gets the index off by one. Because of that it also misses the break for the numbers for the last bucket. There is also a small error introduced because the index calculation uses the range `[0,l-s]` instead of `[s,l]`, which are only the same if `s` equals `0`.

When I write `bucketIndex` as:

```
int bucketIndex( int n, int c, int s, int l )
{
    for(int j = 1; j <= c; j++) {
        if(n > s + (l-s)*j/c) {
            continue;
        } else {
            return j-1;
        }
    }
    return c-1;
}
```

and rewrite the main part of your algorithm as:

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > bucket( c );

for(int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    bucket[ bucketIndex( n[i], c, s, l ) ].push_back( n[i] );
}
```

I get the items properly inserted into their buckets.